# slick lightbox not working in RTL direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, slick.js, arabic-support

I have a group of images on which I have used slick lightbox.
https://github.com/mreq/slick-lightbox

I am currently working for an arabic site and that is why I want the carousel to work in  Right-to-left direction.When I put the dir="html" attribute in the html tag,it breaks the carousel.It works with the rtl tag strictly on the parent of slick lightbox.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/shivanit2/pen/jQBrwB

HTML markup

```
    <html dir="rtl">
  <body>
      <div class="content">
        <h1 class="content-title">Gallery</h1>

        <div class="gallery js-gallery">
          <div class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
  $('.js-gallery').slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.js-gallery-popup img',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)'
  });
```

What modifications can I do to make the plugin to support RTL?

Comment: The link to the codepen doesn't work. Make sure you provide a working example. Take the time to make the example work if you want people to spend their time in helping you.

Comment: @Dekel The link is working.If you click on the image links,you can see the lightbox popup on it.

Comment: So what is the issue there? I don't see any "left/right" icons and I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I will update my codepen.

Comment: @Dekel I have updated my codepen and the description also.As i have stated above,my carousel breaks when I put the dir="rtl" attribute in the html tag.It works when I put the same attribute on the parent element where the slick lightbox is initialized (.js-gallery).But I have to handle it by putting the attribute on the HTML tag itself.You can click on the image to see the lightbox working.Thanks.

Comment: Don't you dir="rtl" on your html. There are better ways to set rtl on page.

Comment: Okay but I have to handle it with it on my html only. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following style rule to reset the direction.

```
.lg-outer {
    direction: ltr;
}
```